# nvd3 change bar color

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a nvd3 bar chart.

I have click event defined as below:

```
chart.multibar.dispatch.on("elementClick", function(e) {});
```

When I click a bar element, I can get the element information via "e" parameter in the callback and it gives me

```
Object {data: Object, index: 1, color: "rgb(31, 119, 180)"}
```

How can I change a specific bar's color using this index value?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a series index and a point index in series, you need just to find corresponding bar and change its style, like that

```
chart.multibar.dispatch.on("elementClick", function(e)
{
    d3.select('.nv-series-'+ e.seriesIndex +
        ' .nv-bar:nth-child('+ (e.pointIndex + 1) +')').style('fill','red');
});
```